# How to pass widget values from one tab to another tab in GXT?

Tags: java, gxt

Im using GXT 2.1.1, I want to to pass widget values from one tab to another tab.For Example I have created two tabs, the first tab displays all the information of students
in a grid with name, date of join, course selected .... and in other tab i want to
display the student information. When ever a user selects the student from the
grid then that should take him to the next tab with all the details of that particular
student.

Answer (score 0):

Add a listener to the grid (row click) or add a "View" button as one of the columns and add a clickListener to it. In the listener, get the student's id and call a method on the second tab to display the details. Then simply call

```
tabPanel.setSelection(secondTab); 
// tabPanel instance of TabPanel
// secondTab instance of TabItem
```

This should do it.